# Spree - How to get the currently logged admin user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, spree, rails-activejob

I am working with a Delayed Job that, after its completion, sends an email to the admin user that requested it. So, to do this, I need to know who is the admin user that launched it inside the `Spree::Order` model.
I've tried with `try_spree_current_user` and `spree_current_user` but they don't work returning:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `try_spree_current_user' for #<Spree::Order:0x007f93811d7240>):
  app/models/spree/order_decorator.rb:30:in `after_cancel'
  app/controllers/spree/admin/orders_controller_decorator.rb:4:in `cancel'
```

Answer (score 1):

Some how you need to make sure that an admin can launch the order:

```
# Is this user an admin
if spree_current_user.admin?
 # Do some delayed job
 # send the email
 # because spree_current_user.id is the one that sends it
else
 flash[:error] = "You need to be an admin to do this."
 redirect_back_or_default(spree.root_path)
end
```

The above should do what you want to do. You need to test if the current user is an admin then do what he/she needs to do.

I'm sure you meant the [OrdersController](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/frontend/app/controllers/spree/orders_controller.rb)? Not model.